# Convert category to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Currently our site's products are defined by two categories: *food* and *drink*.
It would be useful to convert this categories in two post type for better management of contents.
We cannot find information about this process. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins for that. Like https://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-post-types/